# How to copy multiple charts from Excel and embed it to PPT?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy and paste multiple charts from a sheet in excel to a slide in powerpoint. I have:

```
Public Sub CreateManagmentPres()
Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim ppTextbox As PowerPoint.Shape

Set PPApp = New PowerPoint.Application

PPApp.Visible = True
PPApp.Activate

Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations.Add
'Summary of Assumptions (Cont'd)
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(6, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
PPSlide.Select
PPSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Summary of Assumptions (Cont'd)"

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Case Summary").ChartObjects("Chart Rev").Copy

With PPPres.Slides(6).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, _
   Link:=msoTrue)
End With

PPSlide.Shapes(2).Top = 70
PPSlide.Shapes(2).Left = 11

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Case Summary").ChartObjects("Chart Lev").Copy

With PPPres.Slides(6).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, _
   Link:=msoTrue)
End With

PPSlide.Shapes(3).Top = 70
PPSlide.Shapes(3).Left = 370
```

This returns "Shapes (unknown member).Invalid request. The specified data type is unavailable.
related to `With PPPres.Slides(6).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, _
       Link:=msoTrue)`

I saw a post related changed my code to:

```
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(6, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
PPSlide.Select
PPSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Summary of Assumptions (Cont'd)"


ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Case Summary").ChartObjects("Chart Rev").ChartArea.Copy
With PPPres.Slides(6).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoTrue)
    '~~> Rest of your code here
End With

PPSlide.Shapes(2).Top = 70
PPSlide.Shapes(2).Left = 11
```

Now I get "Object doesn't support this property or method" on:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Case Summary").ChartObjects("Chart Rev").ChartArea.Copy
```

Comment: are you running this code in excel?

Comment: I fought with this for a while. When I finally got it working, I discovered that pasting the charts into PPT ended up with them coming in with different colors and formatting due to the different templates. I ended up making a PPT template in which I _linked_ the charts to the Excel file. Updating the links in PPT gets your updated Excel data.

Comment: Yes, I am running the code in excel. It appeared to be working for a while, then I started getting error messages.

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Case Summary").ChartObjects("Chart Rev").Chart.ChartArea.Copy`  A `ChartObject` is just a container for a `Chart` object, and `ChartArea` is a property of `Chart`

Comment: Tim, thanks for your response! It appears to be running properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
Function PasteChartIntoSlide(theSlide As Object) As Object
    Sleep 100
    On Error Resume Next
    theSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
    PPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
End Function

Function CopyChartFromExcel(theSlide As Object, cht As Chart) As Object
        cht.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture, Size:=xlScreen
End Function

Function PositionChart(leftPos As Integer, rightPos As Integer, widthPos As Integer, heightPos As Integer) As Object
        Sleep 50
        PPT_pres.Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.Left = leftPos
        PPT_pres.Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.Top = rightPos
        PPT_pres.Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.Width = widthPos
        PPT_pres.Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.Height = heightPos
End Function


Function CopyPasteChartFull(Sld As Integer, cht As Chart, leftPos As Integer, rightPos As Integer, widthPos As Integer, heightPos As Integer) As Object
    If PPT Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If PPT_pres Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    Dim mySlide As Object
    Dim myShape As Object

    PPT_pres.Slides(Sld).Select 'Pointless line, just lets the user see what is happening

    Set mySlide = PPT_pres.Slides(Sld)
    With mySlide
    .Select

    'copy chart
    CopyChartFromExcel mySlide, cht

    'Paste chart
    PasteChartIntoSlide mySlide

    'Position Chart
    PositionChart leftPos, rightPos, widthPos, heightPos

    End With

    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Function
```

Comment: This could do with some explanation: what are the differences? what was wrong/what was the meaning of the error?